# Generate a comma-separated list of numbers in a single string

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there a way to generate a comma-separated string of a series of numbers where the "begin" and "end" numbers are provided?

For example, provide the numbers 1 and 10 and the output would be a single value of: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

10/10/2019 edit explaining why I'm interested in this:

My workplace writes queries with several columns in the `SELECT` statement plus aggregate functions. Then a `GROUP BY` clause using the column numbers. I figured using a macro that creates a comma-separated list to copy/paste in would save some time.

```
SELECT t.colA
     , t.colB
     , t.colC
     , t.colD
     , t.colE
     , t.colF
     , t.colG
     , t.colH
     , t.colI
     , t.colJ
     , sum(t.colK) as sumK
     , sum(t.colL) as sumL
     , sum(t.colM) as sumM
  FROM t
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
;
```

Comment: Why do you want this result?

Comment: Added edit to question.

Comment: I would write a list from *1 to n* once and then simply cut & paste what I need :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate your numbers, and xml_agg to generate your string:

```
with  recursive nums (counter) as
( select * from (select  cast(1 as bigint) as counter) t
union all
select
counter + 1
from nums
where counter between 1 and 9
)
 select 
 trim(trailing ',' from cast(xmlagg(cast(counter as varchar(2)) || ',' order by counter) as varchar(100)))
 from nums
```

Comment: why does this add a space after each comma? Otherwise this may work. I could remove them from the aggregated string, but what I'd like to do is put this logic in a UDF where the delimiter can be a parameter. So, this could be a comma (,), comma with a space (, ), pipe (|), etc.

Comment: I think XMLAgg always adds a space in there.  You could use oreplace or a regex to replace the spaces with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check these methods in SQL Server-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Sample') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Sample

Create table #Sample 
(
NUM int
)

declare @n int
select @n=10
insert into #Sample(NUM) 
SELECT NUM FROM (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) AS NUM from sys.columns) A WHERE NUM<=@N

--Method 1 (For SQL SERVER -NEW VERSION Support)
SELECT STRING_AGG(NUM,',') AS EXPECTED_RESULT FROM #Sample
--Method 1 (For SQL SERVER -OLD VERSION Support)
select DISTINCT STUFF(CAST((
    SELECT   ' ,' +CAST(c.num AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM (  
            SELECT num
            FROM   #Sample
        ) c
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 2, '') AS EXPECTED_RESULT
    from #Sample t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a good direct way to generate a series in Teradata. You can fake it a few different ways though. Here's a comma separated list of numbers from 5 to 15, for example:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(rn)|| ',' ) (VARCHAR(10000))))
FROM (SELECT 4 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sys_Calendar."CALENDAR".day_of_calendar) as rn FROM Sys_Calendar."CALENDAR" QUALIFY rn <= 15) t
```

I've only used sys_calendar.calendar here because it's a big table. Any big table would do here though.

Answer (score 0):

While loop seems appropriate

```
declare @begin int=1
declare @end int=11

declare @list varchar(500)

if @begin > @end
    begin
        select 'error, beginning number ' + convert(varchar(500),@begin)
        + ' must not be greater than ending number '
        + convert(varchar(500),@end) + '.' err
        return
    end
    else
        set @list = convert(varchar(500),@begin)
;
while @begin < @end
    begin
        set @begin += 1
        set @list = @list + ',' + convert(varchar(500),@begin)
    end

select @list
```

You might want to use varchar(5000) or something depending on how big you want it to get.

`disclaimer -- I don't know if this works with teradata`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in Teradata:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(src.RowNum) 
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS RowNum
  FROM sys_calendar.calendar
  QUALIFY RowNum BETWEEN <begin_num> AND <end_num>
) src
```

This will give you the output as an `ARRAY` data type, which you can probably cast as a `VARCHAR`.  It also assumes `begin_num > 0` and `<end_num>` is less than the number of rows in the `sys_calendar.calendar` view.  You can always fiddle with this to fit your required range of values.

There are also `DelimitedBuild` UDFs out there (if you can find one) that can be used to convert row values into delimited strings.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way to achieve your goal is this one (no functions, or joins to tables required):

```
WITH RECURSIVE NumberRanges(TheNumber,TheString) AS
(
SELECT 1 AS TheNumber,casT(1 as VARCHAR(500)) as TheString

FROM
( 
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL AS X) X
) DUMMYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT
    TheNumber + 1 AS TheNumber,
    TheString ||',' || TRIM(TheNumber+1) 

FROM NumberRanges
WHERE
TheNumber < 10
)
SELECT TheString
FROM NumberRanges
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TheNumber DESC) = 1;
```

Result String: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10